# CSS/Js - Hide elements and change css when line breaks and elements are at first position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some span elements with display: inline-block for the elements to be on a new line when responsive. As of right now on desktop the look like this:

```
Name | Street | City
```

... when collapsing they look like this:

```
Name 
 | Street 
 | City
```

But what I would actually like is ... when the elements collapse on responsive they should be underneath each other and the | should be gone ... like this:

```
Name 
Street 
City
```

Whats the best way to do this? JS or css I don't mind.

That's my setup:

html:

```
<p class="record-meta">
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <span class="left5">Name</span>
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <span class="left5">|</span>
        <span class="left5">Street</span>
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <span class="left5">|</span>
        <span class="left5">City</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.left5 {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

... Street and City are dynamic elements and width varies ... so I guess I can't set a css @media ...

Comment: you should not use | character for this, you can do this with border from CSS. And then just don't show the border on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that the content length can vary. So you have to calculate the height of `<p class="record-meta">`on window resize on the basic of that you can set line break by adding removing classes to html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hello phillip you can change structure accroding to this because to use span like this is not proper way  and for divider no need to take span we can use it in ::after css..

```css
.record-meta{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-left:0;
}

.record-meta li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 5px;
  position:relative;
}
.record-meta li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -3px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.record-meta li:first-child::after{
  content:none;
}
@media(max-width:576px){
.record-meta li::after{
  content:none;
}
.record-meta li{
  width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<ul class="record-meta">
  <li class="left5">Name</li>
  <li class="left5">Street</li>
  <li class="left5">City</li>
</ul>
```

Remark: if you want to use your excisting structure then add class divider in divider span then use display:none in css and also use margin-left:0 in responsive view..

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using css media queries.

```css
span.block {
    display: inline-block;
  }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  span.block {
    display: block;
  }
  .pipe{
  display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="record-meta">
    <span class="block">
        <span class="left5">Name</span>
    </span>
    <span class="block">
        <span class="left5 pipe">|</span>
        <span class="left5">Street</span>
    </span>
    <span class="block">
        <span class="left5 pipe">|</span>
        <span class="left5">City</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: as mentioned ... Street and City are dynamic elements and width varies ... so I  can't or don't want to set a unflexible css @media ...

Comment: I do suggest reading the question again. What you answered is what OP wants to avoid

Comment: what do you mean by width varies?

Comment: ... well ... Street can be 1 character long ... but also 1000 character long ... so it doesn't make sense to do your magic on a fix width like max-width: 480px :-)

Comment: 1000 char ? is it possible  have that long string without spaces?

Comment: ... this was hypothetical ... the length of the street value varies ...

Comment: even if it varies it will break down as it start getting the width less than 480 or you can define more breakpoints if you want i gave just an example how you can achieve this